# Test results folder does not exis azure ci

Tags: azure, continuous-integration

i setup a a pipeline my issue is i get no ouput in my Test results folder. To analyze the problemm i made samller problem to understand the issue.

If i add the console option:

```
/Logger:trx
```

and set the Batch tests to

```
Based on number of tests and agents
```

i have an output in Test results folder.

But as soon as i set the  Batch tests to:

```
Based on test assemblies
```

the output folder is empty

i also tried to add a Copy files task to copy the files to a diffrent location since i know the VSTest Task v2 will delete the output and copy it to to the azure board.

how can i set the batch sice to based on test assemblies and get the trx files in a directory so i can use them later on in the buildpipeline.